# How to externalize oauthsdk.json in java spring integration project

Tags: java, spring, jboss, oauth-2.0, spring-integration

In my Spring integration project, I am having oauthsdk.json which is used for redirecting and getting the app authenticated. Can this oauthsdk.json be externalized for Jboss ?

Or else I need to use multiple builds for multiple environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Resource` abstraction in Spring, which may represent an external resource: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources